# Finding Conditional Subvector with Maximum Length

Tags: r, vector, count, dplyr

I have a binary vector

```
y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

The probability of getting 1 is `p1 <- sum(y)/length(y)`.

The Probability of getting 0 is `1-p1`

I want to find a sub-vector z (say) of y with MAXIMUM length such that:

z should start from 1 and let the subsequent entry in as long as the probability of getting 1, `q1` (say), i.e. `sum(z)/length(z)` should always be greater than or equal to `p1`.

Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: is this not always just the full vector? It is maximum length and equal to p1

Comment: Dear Chris, It is not always full vector, see if you take `y <-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)` then `p1=0.4545` and required z should start from 8th entry and it would be c(1,1,1,1).

Comment: right but `c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)` is longer than `c(1,1,1,1)`, and >= p1, so both conditions are true, no?

Comment: Actually, technically it is only the entire vector if the first number is one. Otherwise it gets more interesting

Comment: yes, actually I must say z is proper sub-vector as full vector is an obvious case.

Comment: if you have to follow strict logic, the obvious case will generally be the resultant case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way, this really just evaluates all possibilities in the loop:

```
p1 <- sum(y)/length(y)
mlth <- 0
ii <- 0
jj <- 0

for (i in 1:length(y)){
  if(y[i] == 1){
    for (j in i:length(y)){
      if(sum(y[i:j])/length(y[i:j]) > p1 && j - i + 1 >= mlth && j - i + 1 < length(y) ){
        mlth <- j - i + 1
        ii <- i
        jj <- j
      }
    }
  }
}
ii # start position
jj # end position
y[ii:jj] #the vector
```

Comment: Dear Chris, that is interesting actually. When applied to `y <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1)` It gives the z as `1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1` third to eleventh position of y. Probability wise it is OK. But see, I have `p1` as 0.6363. I make things simpler, sub-vector can not start from first entry as first two entries make the probability lesser, in third and fourth same situation arises and so on. So eventually I want to end up at `c(1,1,1,1).`  That is my answer, but this is not giving me that. So, i will start from 1 always and counting the subsequent entries only if the probability condition satisfies.

Comment: @Pankaj sorry, but `c(1,1,1,1)` is wrong based on the conditions you gave. Is there a bigger picture of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I guess, I am not that much good in English. Sorry for the inconvenience. I just edited the post.